# Is there a way to catch unhandled std::exception in MFC app?

Tags: c++, exception, mfc, std

While looking for an answer to this question I came across this question

[In a MFC application, where to put a topmost try/catch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037261/in-a-mfc-application-where-to-put-a-topmost-try-catch)

which says that one should overwrite CWinApp::ProcessWndProcException to catch all exceptions. However this works only for exceptions that inherit from CException. Is there a way to do this for exceptions that inherit from std::exception?

In the end I want put a "topmost" try/catch block somewhere and show a messagebox whenever this try/catch block catches an exception.

Comment: What's stopping you from putting in a catch (const std::exception& e) {} clause in the try/catch block?

Comment: The question is, where this "topmost" try/catch block should be.

Comment: If you throw the exception from a dialog it will hang your app - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143006/why-does-my-mfc-app-hang-when-i-throw-an-exception

Comment: What kind of application? SDI, MDI, dialog,...?

Answer (score 1):

How about handling it in the CWinApp overrides?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akdx0603.aspx

So, there will be a class that overrides CWinApp or CWinAppEx in your application. The CWinApp::Run function is the message handler. This would be a good place put your try catch over the base implementation. Kind of like this:

```
MyApp::Run(...)
{
    try {
        CWinApp::Run(...);
    }
    catch stuff ...
}
```

Comment: This won't help. It's not going to be able to catch C++ exceptions before they cross into OS code from message handlers, for example. And pretty much any code in a Windows application is running in response to a window message.